# Online platforms for teachers to discuss matters related to mathematics

Tags: secondary-education, onlineplatforms

As we all agree mathematics educators community is doing a great service as an international platform regarding teachers issues related to mathematics education. Not all but only personally motivated teachers join and get the full use by actively involving. Sometimes lack of participation may be a result of language barriers or because of less self motivation. What measures would you suggest to motivate teachers to get the full use of online sources such as communities like this one ? 
As a local platform for mathematics teachers we have one which was created for us in last year. But only few are interested to be active there. My suggestion is you may need to select about 100 teachers who can be easily motivated and give a plan to keep the platform live. This selection can be done by the help of Zonal Directors because they can do it by the assistance of principals of schools. What would you suggest to encourage teachers regarding this and how can you compare the participation of your mathematics teachers in a local online platform similar to this mathematics educators?

Comment: @JohnOmielan thanks for your suggestion , I will look into that.  Actually I wanted to what is going on in other countries because it may be important when I make my suggestions for the development of mathematics education here in my country.

Answer (score 2):

There exist research on online communities for teacher professional development. I am not a scholar of this, having read one example research proposal in an appendix to [1], but the search term "teacher online learning community" seems to be a good start: https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=teacher+online+learning+community

I recommend doing an informal literature search on the subject to get a sense of what is known. Hopefully something useful comes up.

My general experience is that getting any online community up and going requires a committed group of people who are already into it, as a minimum requirement.

I know that teachers in Norway have a number of Facebook groups and such, for example one on using Minecraft for mathematics teaching (since master students of mine wrote on that), but I have not delved deeper into these.

[1] MAXWELL, Joseph A. Qualitative research design: An interactive approach. Sage publications, 2013.